# CSS3 hexagonal button with border and rounded corners

Tags: css, button, svg, css-shapes

I have image and it has very odd shape : flat hexagon with borders and rounded corners. I would like to make it with *CSS*.
I have tried to make it with *CSS* so that it can expand dynamicaly for longer text but its not working for me.

Here is the image

[image: Hexagonal button with rounded corners and border]

Comment: For what purpose you are doing it? It won't be supported in older browsers.

Comment: Frankly, I'd use an SVG bg image.

Comment: This is a duplicate of a similar hexagon image question

Answer (score 11):

### CSS :

You can achieve this shape with 2 3d transformed pseudo elements :

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 50px;
  perspective: 30px;
}
div:after,div:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  background: orange;
  border: 2px solid darkorange;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div:before {
  right: 50%;
  transform-origin: 100% 0;
  transform: rotateY(-10deg);
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  border-width: 3px 0 3px 5px;
}
div:after {
  left: 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotateY(10deg);
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  border-width: 3px 5px 3px 0;
}
body{text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div>some text</div><br/><br/>
<div>some longer text</div>
```

*Note that you will need to add the appropriate vendor prefixes to maximize browser support. See [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d) for more information.*

---

### SVG :

Another alternative is to use an inline svg with the polygon element :

```css
div{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    padding:20px 50px;
}
svg{
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0;
    z-index:-1;
    min-width:100%; min-height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn">
    some text
    <svg viewbox="0 0 100 30">
        <polygon points="2 8 50 2 98 8 98 22 50 28 2 22" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" stroke="darkorange" fill="orange" />
    </svg>
</div>
<div class="btn">
    some longer text
    <svg viewbox="0 0 100 30">
        <polygon points="2 8 50 2 98 8 98 22 50 28 2 22" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" stroke="darkorange" fill="orange" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for quick answer. What will happen for safari browsers?
As you know safari will not support "CSS3 Transform"

Comment: @SamIR if you check [canIuse for 3d transforms](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d), you will see that they are supported by safari with the `-webkit-` vendor prefix.

Comment: I just created demo html page with adding vendor prefix code but still it does not help me to making those buttons. Please check this fiddle in safari. 
https://jsfiddle.net/vnonx5yj/

Comment: @SamIR please check your version of safari (especialy if you are using windows) is it more than 4?

Comment: Yes I am checking on my windows pc and safari version is 5.1.7

Comment: @SamIR please note that safari on windows is old (current version is 8). Also, you didn't add the `-webkit-` prefix for the `perspective` declaration in the last fiddle you shared. I added it here https://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/vnonx5yj/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77891/discussion-between-sam-ir-and-web-tiki).

Answer (score -1):

I copied the styling from [here](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) and made slight changes to match roughly what your button looks like:

```
#hexagon {
width: 200px;
height: 30px;
background: orange;
position: relative;}

#hexagon:before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: -15px;
left: 0;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 100px solid transparent;
border-right: 100px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 15px solid orange;}

#hexagon:after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
bottom: -15px;
left: 0;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 100px solid transparent;
border-right: 100px solid transparent;
border-top: 15px solid orange;}
```

hexagon is for the middle sector of the shape

Hexagon:after is for the bottom part of the shape

Hexagon:before is for the top part of the shape

The width specified in #hexagon would need to match border-left + border-right in :before and :after
i.e (200px = 100px+100px)

The height specified in #hexagon would need to match border-top + border-bottom of :before and :after i.e (30px = 15px + 15px)

HTML would simply be

`<div id="hexagon">`

So far I haven't been able to see how to have the border effect you're using, but if someone could extend onto this I think it would be possible.

Comment: Your solutions won't work for me. because I need button that dynamically change its width based on texts. Sorry for that. What you suggested was static width.